# Multiprocessing a function from main forking main as well in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to do multiprocessing of a function 5 times by using python multiprocessing.Process library

To my surprise I am also getting the prints that I have added 5 times more..my intuition is that main is also getting called 5 times.

I added prints in the train function that I need to process 5 times I can see multiprocessing happening from the prints.But I am unable to figure it out why main is also getting called 5 times.

Here is my code..Can someone please help a check what's wrong with this code.

```
def train(rank,params, shared_model, optimizer,ticker):
    try:
        print("rank:",str(rank)," ",str(ticker),"\n")
        f.write("rank:"+str(rank)+" "+str(ticker)+"\n")
        data= pd.read_csv(ticker + '.csv')
        data = data.dropna()
        count = 0
        max_timesteps = int(data.shape[0]*0.8)
        
        data = torch.DoubleTensor(np.asarray(data))

        env = ENV(state_dim, action_dim, data)
    
        # init training variables
    
        state = env.reset()
        done = True
        episode_length = 0
        count = 0
        while count<max_timesteps-1:
            episode_length += 1
            if done:
                cx = Variable(torch.zeros(1, state_dim))
                hx = Variable(torch.zeros(1, state_dim))
            else:
                cx = Variable(cx.data)
                hx = Variable(hx.data)
            values = []
            log_probs = []
            rewards = []
            entropies = []
            for step in range(max_timesteps):
                value, action_values, (hx, cx) = model((Variable(state.unsqueeze(0)), (hx, cx)))
                prob = F.softmax(action_values,dim = 0)
                log_prob = F.log_softmax(action_values,dim = 0)
                entropy = -(log_prob * prob).sum(1)
                entropies.append(entropy)
                action = prob.multinomial(num_samples=1).data
                log_prob = log_prob.gather(1, Variable(action))
                values.append(value)
                log_probs.append(log_prob)
                state, reward, done = env.step(action.numpy())
                print(ticker," reward", reward , " rank:",rank)
                count+=1
                done = (done or count == max_timesteps-2)
                reward = max(min(reward, 1), -1)
                if done:
                    episode_length = 0
                    state = env.reset()
                
                rewards.append(reward)
                if done:
                    break
            R = torch.zeros(1, 1)
            if not done:
                value, _, _ = model((Variable(state.unsqueeze(0)), (hx, cx)))
                R = value.data
            values.append(Variable(R))
            policy_loss = 0
            value_loss = 0
            R = Variable(R)
            gae = torch.zeros(1, 1)
            for i in reversed(range(len(rewards))):
                R = params.gamma * R + rewards[i]
                advantage = R - values[i]
                value_loss = value_loss + 0.5 * advantage.pow(2)
                TD = rewards[i] + params.gamma * values[i + 1].data - values[i].data
                gae = gae * params.gamma * params.tau + TD
                policy_loss = policy_loss - log_probs[i] * Variable(gae) - 0.01 * entropies[i]
                
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            (policy_loss + 0.5 * value_loss).backward()
            torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 40)
            optimizer.step()
            f.flush()

    except:
        print(ticker)
        traceback.print_exc()
        var = traceback.format_exc()
        f.write(str(ticker)+"\n")
        f.write("exception:\n"+str(var))
        f.flush()


# Implementing the Adam optimizer with shared states


class Params():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lr = 0.001
        self.gamma = 0.99
        self.tau = 1.
        self.seed = 1
        self.num_processes = 5
        self.num_steps = 20
        self.max_episode_length = 10000
        self.env_name = 'Breakout-v0'


params = Params()

state_dim = 6
action_dim = 3

model = ActorCritic(state_dim, action_dim)
model.share_memory()
optimizer = SharedAdam(model.parameters(), lr=params.lr)
optimizer.share_memory()


# set the parameters

epochs = 1
state_dim = 6
action_dim = 3
max_action = 1
idx = 0
file_name = "%s" % ("computational__reward")
directory="./pytorch_models"

# instantiate policy

tickers = pd.read_csv("tickers.csv")
indices = tickers['Symbol']
jobs = []

#indices = ['FTK']
for ep in range(1):
    print("epoch:",ep)
    f.write("epoch:"+str(ep)+"\n")
    for ticker in indices:
        try:
            for rank in range(0, params.num_processes): # making a loop to run all the other processes that will be trained by updating the shared model
                if __name__ == '__main__':
                    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=train, args=(rank, params, model, optimizer,ticker,))
                    jobs.append(p)
                    p.start()
            for p in jobs: # creating a pointer that will allow to kill all the threads when at least one of the threads, or main.py will be killed, allowing to stop the program safely
                p.join()
                

            model.save("A3C_multi"+ str(ep)+"_" + file_name, directory="./pytorch_models")
            f.flush()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            traceback.print_exc()
            var = traceback.format_exc()
            f.write(str(ticker)+"\n")
            f.write("exception:\n"+str(var))
model.save("A3C"+ str(ep)+"_" + file_name, directory="./pytorch_models")
```

I am getting this print 6 times:

```
epoch: 0
epoch: 0
epoch: 0
epoch: 0
epoch: 0
epoch: 0
```

Comment: That's missing a lot of code. Please post a proper MCVE that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks ...I have uploaded the full code

Comment: An MCVE is not "the full code". I don't need or want to see your full code. Please reduce the code you have to a minimal example that reproduces the very specific issue you are asking about, and nothing else. There is a good chance that in constructing this example, you will find the source of the problem on your own. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for more information.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for reading...the issue is why main is getting called number of times I want  to start training my function....I assume there is something wrong with last 20-30 lines of code that I have already posted earlier...Could you please help a check if multiprocessing part is ok.  I have edited this to only having relevant information..Thanks

Comment: Please really try to understand the instructions. What you have is neither minimal, complete, nor verifiable. I can't run it, and as long as you have references to models and things like that, it's nowhere near minimal. Start from scratch, and build up just the multiprocessing part with a really toy example.

Comment: What operating system are you using Python on? For questions regarding multiprocessing you should always add your operating system to the tags. The inplementation of the `multiprocessing` module is different depending on the operating system, and this has implications for your program.

Comment: Hi, I am using Python 3.7.6 on windows 10....I am unable to get why main is getting called number of times I want to call main function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

Since you are running this on windows, *all code* that is not function or class definitions should be inside the `if __name__ is "__main__"` block.

**Long answer**

On POSIX operating systems, the `multiprocessing` module is implemented using the `fork()` system call, which creates a *copy* of a process.
This is very handy because the second process is completely initialized out of the box.

Microsoft windows does not have this system call. So Python tries to mimick this by starting a new Python interpreter and importing your program as a module.
For this to work well importing your program should *not have side effects*. The best way to achieve that is to put anything that is not a class or function definition inside the `if __name__ is "__main__"` block.

Since part of your code is outside the main block, it will be executed when your program is imported in the newly created Python processes. That is why you are seeing the multiple "epoch" prints.

Comment: Hi,

I am trying this...with this change multiprocessing is not happening simultaneously..Could you please help a check what is wrong here... 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63275146/multiprocessing-not-happening-simultaneously-in-python-3-7-6-on-windows-10

Comment: Your new question is *basically* the same as the one above, and it has the same problem: lack of an MCVE. An MCVE is important because with an MCVE *we can also run* it. Running a program is the best way to find problems.